# Django tests create with PostgresQL multi schema

Tags: django, django-tests, multi-database

I would like to test a create view with django TransactionTestCase. Here is my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        "ENGINE": PG_ENGINE,
        'OPTIONS':{'options': '-c search_path=schema1,schema2,public', 'isolation_level': psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_SERIALIZABLE,},
        'NAME': DB_NAME,
        'USER': DB_USER, 
        'PASSWORD':DB_PASSWD,
        'HOST': HOST_NAME,
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
    'schema2': {
        "ENGINE": PG_ENGINE,
        'OPTIONS':{'options': '-c search_path=schema2, schema1,public', 'isolation_level': psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_SERIALIZABLE,},
        'NAME': DB_NAME,
        'USER': DB_USER, 
        'PASSWORD':DB_PASSWD,
        'HOST': HOST_NAME,
        'PORT': '5432',
        # 'TEST_MIRROR': 'default',
        "TEST": {
            "NAME": "schema2",
            "OPTIONS":{'options': '-c search_path=schema2,schema1,public'}
           
        },
    },
```

And my test case:

```
class CreateTestCase(TransactionTestCase):
    
    databases={'schema2', 'default', }


    def setUp(self):
        self.client=Client()
        self.user= Model_in_default.objects.create(name='test', username='test', permission='Admin')
        self.model_in_schema2=Model_in_schema2.objects.create(name='for_test', urlname='fortest', some_id=1, parent_some_id=2000, rank='test', code='tetcode', other_names='test' )
        
        self.create_url=reverse('model_create')   
    
    def test_create_url_is_resolved(self):
        url=self.create_url
        self.assertEquals(resolve(url).func.view_class,ModelListView)
    

    # def test_create(self):
    #     request=self.client.get(self.create_url, follow=True)
    #     request.user = self.user
    #     request.model_in_schema2=self.model_in_schema2
    #     response = ModelCreateView.as_view()(request)
```

When I run test - 'test_create_url_is_solved' firstly, I got error:
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist...

My problem might be I put default django migartions and some models in default schema while some other models in schema2. I added OPTIONS to config test database and apparently it is not the right way...
Any ideas on how to create test case in this situation?
Thank you.